# Как понять что канал для записи закрыт

Tags: golang

Добрый день, у меня возник вопрос по использованию каналов в golang, точнее как определить что канал закрыт
Вот пример:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func run () chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    i := 0
    go func() {
        fmt.Println("Init loop")
        for {
            i++
            msg := fmt.Sprintf("Message #%d", i)
            fmt.Println("Send:", msg)
            select {
            case c <- msg:
                fmt.Println("Sent message")
            default:
                fmt.Println("default?")
            }
            time.Sleep(time.Millisecond * 1500)
        }
        fmt.Println("Shutdown loop")
    }()
    return c
}
func main() {
    c := run()
    for i:= 1; i < 10; i++ {
        if i == 5 {
            fmt.Println("Close input chan")
            close(c)
        }
        fmt.Printf("Receive #%d: '%s'\n", i, <-c)
    }
}
```

ссылка на код https://repl.it/ENFk/0
Собственно вопрос в том что-бы при закрытии канала (строка 34) управление передавалось на "Shutdown loop"

Comment: P.S. Все это делается для того чтобы корректно остановить goroutone в run(). Про использование семафоров и каналов для этого - в курсе.
Вопрос в том, возможно-ли для этого использовать сам исходящий канал

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Закрытый канал не блокируется на чтение. Специальная конструкция

```java
Loop:
    for {
        select {
        case val, ok :=<- someChan:
            if !ok {
                // канал закрыт
                break Loop
            }
            // получены данные, работа с val
        default:
            // канал пуст, что-то делать
        }
    }
```

В данном случае, `ok` будет истиной только для открытого канала. Но при закрытии по каналу будут приходить пустые сообщения постоянно и `ok` будет ложью.

Однако вышеприведённая конструкция оптимальна только если нужно выполнять действие в `default`-ветке. Т.е. что-то делать, когда сообщений нет. Есть более простая и понятная конструкция

```java
for val := range someChan {
    // получено сообщение
}
// канал закрыт
```

В этом случае канал читается, используя `for-range`. Когда канал будет закрыт и из него будет прочитано последнее сообщение, произойдёт выход из цикла.

#### Запись

Запись в закрытый канал вызывает панику. Текущая схема некорректна. Требуется добавлять ещё какой-нибудь примитив синхронизации, что б не происходило записи в закрытый канал. Вот пример на [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/aHGzTiPSQv). И конструкция `case-default` тут не поможет.

Собственно ответ на вопрос. В данном случае никак.

Пояснение.

Дизайн приложения должен быть таким, что сторона создающая канал, его же и закрывает и пишет в него то же она. Более того, в этих случая рекомендуется, что б функция возвращала канал только для чтения

```
func run () <-chan string {
    c := make(chan string)
    // [...]
}
```

В этом случае, ошибку будет видно на этапе компиляции (пример: [play.golang.org](https://play.golang.org/p/xdiVGC9Y-9)).

#### recover()

Конечно можно в отложенном вызове вызвать `recover()`, чтобы подавить панику. Но это в корне неправильно. По этой причине пример я не привожу.

Comment: С чтением из каналов все понятно и можно найти массу примеров на эту тему.
Поэтому интересует именно каналы используемые для записи. Вопрос куда передается управление в go-routone (строки 12-25) после того как канал закрывается?

Comment: @chernomyrdin, обновил

Answer (score 0):

> Вопрос куда передается управление в go-routone (строки 12-25) после того как канал закрывается?

Спит 1500 мс. За это время main успевает завершится, поэтому не наступает паника. Добавляем таймаут в main - все встает на свои места:

https://go.dev/play/p/6aACI5TG-9r

Ну и да, закрывать должен пишущий код, сообщить ему, что пора, можно разными способами например так:

https://go.dev/play/p/24gkaThQpgM

Сори, что побеспокоил, но может кому пригодиться...